# I am getting one long string back from an API call that I need to turn into an array. The values are comma separated. What is the best way to do this?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I am working with data from an api that is returning values formatted like this for a few of the keys:

```
      "key_one": [
        "[\"Some Value One\",\"Some Value Two\",\"Some Value Three\"]"
      ],
      "key_two": [
        "[\"Some Value Four\",\"Some Value Five\"]"
      ],
```

The values of the keys come back as an array, but the array contains just one long string. I am looking for a way for taking **THIS**:

```
["[\"Some Value One\",\"Some Value Two\",\"Some Value Three\"]"]
```

and turning it into **THIS**:

```
["Some Value One","Some Value Two","Some Value Three"]
```

I have a feeling Regex would be best for this, but I am still a complete novice with Regex and my attempts so far havent gotten me anywhere.

I also attempted to do a basic for loop that looked for the presence of the " mark, and then checked to see if the character after wasnt a ',' and tried to push or += the letters into a string and then into an array at the end to return, but it was becoming a mess and wasn't working either.

I am hoping someone here can show me a more elegant solution.....

Answer (score 2):

You ca try `JSON.parse`

```js
const obj = {
  "key_one": [
    "[\"Some Value One\",\"Some Value Two\",\"Some Value Three\"]"
  ],
  "key_two": [
    "[\"Some Value Four\",\"Some Value Five\"]"
  ]
}

for (let keys in obj) {
  obj[keys] = JSON.parse(obj[keys])
}
console.log(obj)
```